# On Windows 8 and Internet Information Service 8.5 - how to setup PHP?

Tags: php, windows, iis

Let me begin by saying that I am very new to Microsoft's Internet Information Service. I need to setup IIS on my PC and it should also execute PHP files. So far I got everything installed and running - the latest PHP and enabled IIS service. I can view the Default Webpages (*.html) files ONLY. It will not execute PHP files. If I try to request any PHP files, I get 403 error.

I have been researching online and seems to be more confused about setting up PHP (extension) on IIS. Some websites say you need to configure PHP through its MANAGER. Others say I need to add Role and FastCGImodule through IIS manager. According to Microsoft I need to rename php.ini-development to php.ini and point php to some DLL file.

I am using Windows 8, IIS 8.5 and PHP 5.6. I hope someone could point me in the direction.

Comment: Are you running http://php.iis.net/?

Comment: Are you developing a .net item? Otherwise I would use http://www.wampserver.com/en/. Windows Apachi MySql Php

Comment: We have IIS7.5 rather than 8.5 but we use Web Platform Installer which does all the  basic PHP installation for us, with Fast-CGI etc.  You need to run WPI within IIS Manager to get the right packages and they aren't right up to date but it works quite well for us.

Comment: @Mark_1 What do you mean I need to run WPI within IIS Manager? I see that you can download the WPI executable off the Internet and run, but how do you run it within IIS.

Comment: It looks like you have figured this out yourself but just for completeness   

Once Web Platform Installer is installed you can run it from Windows and it will show you options suitable for Windows.  But what you need to do is start up IIS manager, you will see Web Platform Installer there too and if you run it within IIS you will get all the options suitable for the IIS environment (like your PHP installation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try the answer posted to heart, but I kept running into problems. In fact, I also followed the Microsoft step by step PHP setup tutorial to the TEETH. I still couldn't get PHP working on my IIS. Although Microsoft warned against using Windows Platform Installer(WPI), I downloaded WPI and ran the installer. Under frameworks, I found PHP 5.6 and clicked on Add button. Then, clicked on the Install button. It took only about 30 seconds to install. Just to be sure. I checked IIS manager and there it was PHP Manager. After opening PHP manager I noticed that all the settings were there and enabled and it already had 15 different extension enabled. Plus, it also had about 35 extension disabled, but it gives you option to enable them right there.

Now, my PHP files are rendered as expected. I even did phpinfo(); and the browser displayed all the PHP settings and information. :)

Comment: Where did you find Microsoft's advice not to use Web Platform Installer?  Their PHP versions aren't as up to date as I would like  but I thought they were still recommending it.

Comment: @Mark_1 They said if you are a beginner it is best to use WPI. If not they suggested that you should follow their steps listed in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this up manually or with the IIS Manager. I would set this up my own, so you know whats going on.

You will need to setup the CGI role feature. This includes FastCGI. Here is some information how to do that: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/cgi

Then you will need the PHP package somewhere. Lets say in C:\PHP. You can change that if you want.

You will need the fastCGI settings. You can easily set this up by commandline:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/fastCGI /+[fullPath='C:\php\php-cgi.exe',activityTimeout='1200',requestTimeout='1200',arguments='-c%20C:\php\php.ini']
```

This example uses a timeout of 20min.

This will set the handler:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:handlers /+[name='PHP_FastCGI',path='*.php',verb='*',modules='FastCgiModule',scriptProcessor='"C:\php\php-cgi.exe|-c%20C:\php\php.ini"',responseBufferLimit='0',resourceType='Either']
```

php.ini setup:

```
[cgi-fcgi]
fastcgi.impersonate=1
cgi.force_redirect=0
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
```

For write access you will need to grant "modify" access for the the IURS.

More Information: http://php.net/manual/de/install.windows.iis7.php

Comment: I was able to follow through with your answer and I thought I covered everything. When I try to request a simple php file, browser is showing error 500 - Internal Server Error. So, with more testing I found some information related to this error - `Module - FastCgiModule` `Notification - ExecuteRequestHandler` `Handler - PHP_FastCGI` `Error Code - 0x8007010b` Any idea?

Comment: It looks like a common windows error code when a desired directory is not existing. Can you please provide your php.ini file and information about your installation? PHP directory, website document root and so on. Which PHP version did you use? VC11 NTS?

Comment: You can also provide your IIS config: `%windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`