# Install Subversion PECL extension on Windows

Tags: php, windows, svn, pecl

I am creating a SVN repository system using PHP.
I have Windows OS and i find it difficult to set environment on my PC. I have google and came to know that i need `php_svn.dll` something like that.

But I don't know how to get it work. I have also [looked into php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php) but still did not find proper solution. so can anyone please provide me step by step solution to do this. The first function I am going to execute in `'svn_repos_create(name)'`. I have already executed this function directly but it is giving me error:

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function svn_repos_create() in C:\wamp64\www\ashish\practice\create.php"

So please guide me how to make it workable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Windows 8 and Internet Information Service 8.5 - how to setup PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551347/on-windows-8-and-internet-information-service-8-5-how-to-setup-php)

Comment: You are actually asking how to install the [Subversion PECL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php) on Windows, aren't you?

Comment: Álvaro González  yes something like that. pecl install svn

Comment: Manual is pretty clear: "A DLL for this PECL extension is currently unavailable". So you can either compile it yourself (a pretty difficult task IMHO) or find someone who already did it and shared the result. In any case you need to install the extension, it's not going to show up magically in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **Tortoise SVN**. have a lot of tools that you can use, and is easy to configure...

You'll need create a Repository, make a Checkout in some work directory, and then add your projects files to Commit it.

Links:

[Example of TortoiseSVN with xampp](http://noobcode.blogspot.com.ar/2010/03/what-is-subversion-as-quoted-by.html)

[TortoiseSVN page](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/)

hope this help!

Comment: i want to create php script which create repos. and allow me to fire [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php) all this function. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solution
i have downloaded old php with php_svn.dll
you can google it. 
and then i have downgrade my wamp with old php.
and done.
pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

so it is not possible to do with 5.6,7.0,7.1 version. you can do it with older version only. 
so i have changed my os to UBUNTU. i am using php5.6 and it is working perfectly. 
if you want to work on SVN and PHP then you should be on LINUX OS.

Comment: `svn_repos_create(name)` to run this function first of all i need SVN environment.
now a day with latest php version you can not compile PECL extension for windows.
SVN is supported by PHP5.6 or earlier versions. and i want to use php5.6 so it is not possible for me to do it on windows os.
there for i installed ubuntu and create SVN environment, now all svn commands are working using php.